# Kile : TeX file working on Overleaf not compiling on Kile

Tags: compilation-error, kile

I am compiling a project report that contains at the moment of creation no complicated packages that I might have not installed on Kile (new user here!). Before Kile, I was using Overleaf and the same file is compiling with no errors whatsoever.

I am getting the error output as,

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on "/tmp/kile-livepreview.tNuuwU/Project Draft.log".
```

I run Linux Mint 20.2 (Cinnamon) and the Kile version is 2.9.93

For reference, here is my script

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Stellar Project (Lane-Emden Equations and Polytropic model)}
\author{Manu Upadhyay,209109}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Theoretical Background}


\section{Statement of the Problem}


\section{Details of the methods of study}

\subsection{Analytical methods}




\section{Results and Discussions}
\section{Limitations}
\section{Relevance}
\begin{thebibliography}{}


\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Just to give a picture of the packages I am working with.
Thanks.
**Edit**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.5)  5 SEP 2021 18:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Project Draft"
(/home/manu/Desktop/Stellar Project SPHY0902/Project Draft
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>)
! Emergency stop.
<*> "Project Draft"
                   
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18 strings out of 483065
 597 string characters out of 5963551
 231997 words of memory out of 5000000
 15149 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 12i,0n,15p,47b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

\
**EDIT : 2**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.5)  5 SEP 2021 18:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Project Draft"
(/home/manu/Desktop/Stellar Project SPHY0902/Project Draft
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>)
! Emergency stop.
<*> "Project Draft"
                   
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18 strings out of 483065
 597 string characters out of 5963551
 231997 words of memory out of 5000000
 15149 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 12i,0n,15p,47b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: So i have to manually find out the error that my code would be producing?

Comment: that's all the error message I'm getting in the log file (what i have posted here)

Comment: Okay, I posted the error message in the question now. My apologies.

Comment: I have posted the edit in the latest part of the question above.

Comment: you are running `pdflatex "project draft" but latex is finding this file in a different directory, that will usually fail, you want to run latex in the directory with the file

Comment: first check that the document runs correctly before worrying about the kile config: cd to `/home/manu/Desktop/Stellar Project SPHY0902/`  and run `pdflatex "Project draft"`  does that run without error (i would not use a space in the file name but it should work)

Comment: I did the above task but I'm still getting an error, I posted the error in the "Edit2" above in the question.

Comment: no the tex log should just show `(./Project Draft` not `(/home/manu/Desktop/Stellar Project SPHY0902/Project Draft` unless something is very strange.